Linq cannot translate property with conversion?
I have found many similar questions, but in none of them have I found the solution to my problem. In an ASP.NET Web API application I have the following Entity:
public class User : BaseEntity
{
        (...)
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; } = new List<Role> { Role.Basic }; // Role is an Enum
        (...)
}

The Entity User has the following configuration:
builder.Entity<User>()
    .Property(u => u.Roles)
    .HasConversion(
    new RoleListValueConverter(),
    new ValueComparer<List<Role>>(
        (c1, c2) => RoleListHasher.Hash(c1!) == Utils.RoleListHasher.Hash(c2!),
        c => RoleListHasher.Hash(c),
        c => c.ToList()));

When I try to query the users that contain a specific role, I receive the error The LINQ expression 'r => (int)r' could not be translated ....
This is my query:
var role = (int)Role.Basic;

query = query.Select(u => new { User = u, Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => ((int)r)) })
    .Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r == role))
    .Select(u => u.User);

Could someone please tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks a lot in advance.

It is known limitation. Properties with conversion cannot be used in LINQ queries. There is no possibility to generate SQL from compiled C# methods.

Hi sir. Thanks for your quick response. Is there no possibility of creating a function using SQL language to filter by a role? I've never done anything like that before, I'm just thinking of a possible solution.

Better to create many-to-many relationship User.Roles and Role.Users
